# Convert date and time in dart

Tags: flutter, date, dart

from API I am getting this:
"2022-05-12T15:55:03.000000Z"
My question is, how can I make it:
12.05.2022, 15:55

My question is, is here any easy way? Otherwise I can slowly and partially convert it with string methods, but I guess there must be better, more proper way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can user DateFormat to get a date as string formatted the way you want

```
String x = "2022-05-12T15:55:03.000000Z";

DateTime y = DateTime.parse(x);
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(y);
  print(formatted); // 12.05.2022, 15:55
```

Comment: The [`DateFormat` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) can be found in the [`intl` package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).